# Is it possible to deploy an outlook web add-in via a setup file?

Tags: office-js

I'm aware of the options available for add-in deployment from the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish). I'm asking if there is another way to deploy the app on the user machine automatically instead of having the user search for the add-in on the Office Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. MSI installers can be used for deploying Office/Outlook COM based add-ins (for example, VSTO).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution?view=vs-2019

However Microsoft has created new add-ins that have support for Office Online, mobile apps, and Mac. To deploy these add-ons you have to use the Office 365 Admin Center Centralized Deployment. This will not require a user to go to the store and show any available Add-ins in the Admin Managed page. [image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment

Answer (score 1):

The article that you linked to has all the deployment options. The one called Centralized Deployment has the effect of deploying the add-in to users automatically. What is the deployment scenario that isn't satisfied by those options?

Comment: Thanks for answering. The centralized deployment option is really for organizations but the scenario I'm thinking of is an installer for a different windows app and bundling in the add-in with that installer instead of having the user navigate the office store and install the add-in manually.